# Is if possible to use variable in if statement that is not true or false

Tags: jquery

Wondering if this is possible and if so , how ?

```
var variable = true;
if (variable) {
    var newVariable = "$('table').find('tr').length > 1)";
} else {
    var newVariable = "$('table').find('tr').length > 4)";
}
if (newVariable){ // if $('table').find('tr').length > 1)
    console.log(newVariable)
}
```

I would like the if to look like this by inserting using the newVariable when variable is true

```
if ($('table').find('tr').length > 1)){
    console.log(newVariable)
}
```

of if variable is false then this

```
if ($('table').find('tr').length > 4)){
    console.log(newVariable)
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it? This is a fundamental behavior of JavaScript. Here is some documentation on what is considered [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) and [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) in JavaScript. Non-empty strings are truthy. If you're wanting to evaluate an expression you can use [eval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp) but that's generally not a good idea. Why not just set the variable equal to the result of your condition rather than putting the condition in a string?

Comment: Why are you enclosing code in strings?

Comment: Why are you not doing `if (variable) {
    var newVariable = $('table').find('tr').length > 1;
} else {
    var newVariable = $('table').find('tr').length > 4);
}`

Comment: better yet `const minNumElems = variable ? 1 : 4; const isValid = $('table').find('tr').length > minNumElems; if (isValid) {}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`newVariable` is a string. Using it in an `if` condition is not going to execute it, it will just test if the string is empty or not.

You can use a function instead, and call it in the `if`.

```
var variable = true;
if (variable) {
    var newVariable = () => $('table').find('tr').length > 1;
} else {
    var newVariable = () => $('table').find('tr').length > 4;
}
if (newVariable()){
    console.log(newVariable)
}
```

Comment: unclear why a function would be needed. Seems overkill.

Comment: Good point. I was thinking that we needed to avoid evaluating both expressions, but the first `if` already accomplishes that.

Comment: I am really just at a loss what OP is actually trying to accomplish :)

Answer (score 0):

Unclear why you would need to use strings. Only way you could do that is use eval or new Function and that is not a good idea. Seems like the code could be cleaned up to be either

```js
var newVariable;
if (variable) {     
  newVariable = $('table').find('tr').length > 1; 
} else {     
  newVariable = $('table').find('tr').length > 4;
}
if (newVariable) {
  console.log('here');
}
```

better yet reducing the code with ternary

```js
const minNumElems = variable ? 1 : 4;
const isValid = $('table').find('tr').length > minNumElems;
if (isValid) {
  console.log('here');
}
```

Or better yet using ternary